# Can someone please explain Convex Optimization without Hessian Matrices?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research

I need help. In my class we're not using Hessian matrices with our convex optimization. I don't really understand how to find out if it's concave or convex. All the videos I look at and articles I read pretty much only use Hessian Matrices and what not.

I don't really understand this Convex Theorem either. `f(λx+(1−λ)y)≥λf(x)+(1−λ)f(y).
f(λx+(1−λ)y)≥λf(x)+(1−λ)f(y)  f(λx+(1−λ)y)≤λf(x)+(1−λ)f(y)` It seems like it's saying the function should be larger than the extrema for concavity and less than for convexity?

I get what concave and convex mean, I looked at a fantastic video that explained where they derived that Convex theorem equation, and I get that you should use the second derivative. But I don't really understand how you find out or use the second derivative.

I'm terribly sorry. Calculus was several years ago. Do you think  someone could please help me out?
I know this has to be a very annoying and simple question for you guys...

Comment: Humility is important, but I don't think this is annoying or simple at all. No need to fret. Unfortunately I know very little about the subject myself, or I'd jump in.

Comment: Those inequalities say that if you have two points $(x,f(x)),(y,f(y))$ on the curve of a convex function, the graph of the convex function between those points lies below the line between them. It's reversed for a concave function. Try sketching this out for $f(x)=x^2$ (a convex function) and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ (a concave function).

Comment: Deriving the Hessian is _one way_ to prove convexity, but it is not the only way, and of course it's useless for nondifferentiable functions. I recommend the book Convex Optimization by Boyd & Vandenberghe (free downloadable available) as a good text. That said, if you struggle with vector calculus, I'm afraid you're going to have quite a difficult time navigating any decent text on convex optimization.

Comment: As for the role of Hessian matrices, in the 1D case the idea is that if the first derivative is zero and the second derivative is positive (resp. negative), then whichever way you go from the point, the value goes up (resp. down). In higher dimensions we have more directions than just left and right, but the principle is still the same: we want to guarantee that whatever direction we go from our minimum (resp. maximum) point, the function values go up (resp. down). Seeking out a point where the gradient vanishes and the Hessian is positive (resp. negative) definite is how we do this.

Comment: @TheCount Thank you for saying that. I always worry I bother people.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for explaining the theorem so well!
If I may ask, how do you find out if a simple polynomial function is concave or convex using the second derivative? So you set the second derivative equal to 0 and if it's nonnegative than it's convex? But there has to be more to it than that, right? Like just with simple polynomial functions. Or right now at least in my class...

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you for the advice!
Well it's just that calculus was several years ago and I forgot a lot. I got A's in all three Calculus courses.
I'm only in Operations Research 1 and we're doing nonlinear programming at the moment. Linear programming was very easy. I'm just struggling with this one at the moment...

Comment: @MorbidTag Everyone bothers some one, but unless the fraction of the bothered people seems very high, I would not worry about. And you're very welcome.

Comment: MorbidTag, in that case, I would seek out books like Boyd & Vandenberghe and dig in. You might struggle with those sections that require comfort with vector calculus, but at least you'll see plenty of derivation that requires no calculus whatsoever.